# Setting First Option in <Select>

Tags: spring

I'm using Spring Forms to display a list of countries using `<form:select />`  tag. The list is sorted alphabetically but I'd like to place "United States" as the first option, but not selected by default

The rendered HTML is as follows (the values are the country IDs, & the IDs will never change)

```
<select id="countries">
    <option value="1">Argentina</option>
    <option value="2">Columbia</option>
    <option value="3">United States</option>
</select>
```

Could this be accomplished with a Spring Expression? Thanks much!

Comment: You're asking for a Spring solution, right? Not an after-the-fact HTML/JavaScript/jQuery solution?

Comment: That's right, meant to include that thanks!

Comment: Okay, cool. I've removed the [tag:javascript] and [tag:jquery] tags because they're irrelevant if you're looking to solve this with Spring (which is the right place to solve it IMHO).

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)

```
<form:select path="countries" id="countries">
<c:forEach var="countries" items="${countriesList}">
    <form:option <c:if test="${countries.id==3}"> selected="true" </c:if> value="${countries.id}"> ${countries.name}
    </form:option>
</c:forEach>
</form:select>
```